# OkHttp: avoid leaked connection warning

Tags: java, memory-leaks, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 3, and I keep getting leaked connection warnings:

```
WARNING: A connection to https://help.helpling.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
Jul 14, 2016 6:57:09 PM okhttp3.ConnectionPool pruneAndGetAllocationCount
```

Everytime I get a `ResponseBody`, I either call `.string()` which supposedly closes the stream for me, or I explicitly close it in a `finally` block, in the following way:

```
ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
try (Reader responseReader = responseBody.charStream()) {
    ...
}
finally {
    responseBody.close();
}
```

My application makes intense use of the network, and yet that warning appears frequently. I never observed any problem caused by this presumed leak, but I would still like to understand *if* and *what* I am doing wrong.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By upgrading to OkHttp 3.7, Eclipse started warning me of potential resource leaks. I found my problem to be in this method I wrote:

```
public static Response getResponse(HttpUrl url, OkHttpClient client) throws IOException {
    Builder request = new Request.Builder().url(url);
    Response response = client.newCall(request.build()).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        boolean repeatRequest = handleHttpError(response);
        if (repeatRequest)
            return getResponse(url, client, etag);
        else
            throw new IOException(String.format("Cannot get successful response for url %s", url));
    }
    return response;
}
```

I assumed that by always calling `getResponse(url, client).body().string()` the stream would close automatically. But, whenever a response was unsuccessful, an exception would raise before the execution of `.string()`, thus the stream would remain open.

Adding an explicit close in case of unsuccessful response solved the problem.

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    boolean repeatRequest = handleHttpError(response);
    response.close();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in the other answers, you have to close the response. A slightly cleaner approach would be to declare the `ResponseBody` in the try block, so that it will be automatically closed.

```
try(ResponseBody body = ....){
....
}
```

Comment: For some it might be slightly nicer to close the `Response` rather than the `ResponseBody` directly.  That is, closing Response closes the underlying ResponseBody ... for my use cases closing Response works a little bit better.

Comment: I could not use a try-with-resources approach, because my method needed to return the `Response` instance, to be read by another method if successful (see my own answer).

Comment: if you use Kotlin and the new okhttpclient v4, simply consume the response using a `client.newCall(..).execute().use {response -> ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Even with success, I need to close the response for me. And *body().string()* did not close the connection. So explicitly we need to close the connection even if the response is 200 OK. So better put it in finally {... } block.

```
try{
 response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (HttpStatus.valueOf(response.code()).is2xxSuccessful()) {

    try (ResponseBody body = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE)) {
      Identifier identifier = objectMapper.readValue(body.string(), Identifier.class);
      // response.close();
      return identifier;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      // response.close();
      throw new SomeException( .....);
    }
  } else {
    // response.close();
    throw new SomeException(...);
  } ...
 } catch(RuntimeException ex){
   .......
  }
   finally { 
    if (response != null) {
    response.close();
  }
}
```